# Problem with data optimization after sum of squared errors in Python

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, optimization, least-squares, python

I have a script that allows you to optimize some data (goals from all matches of a football team), after plotting the sum of the squared errors. The aim is to find a final parameter that is more precise than the arithmetic mean, because i will later use this parameter in the Poisson distribution to calculate the specific and individual numbers of exact goals. Initially I used the Poisson average, but I would like a more precise and better parameter.

I'm not sure if the script is correct. The problem is that I'm not sure if the final parameter is correct (`1.69`), because i'm not sure that the step of plotting the sum of squared errors with respect to the Poisson parameter μ is what i really need or if I need something different (maybe I should have solved the least squares problem?), OR i'm also not sure if the optimization with `BFGS` is what I really need.

For example, considering the list `goals` = [1, 2, 2, 2, 1] which has an average of `1.6`, then the final parameter of the script is `1.69`.

What do you think is wrong with my code and how could I improve it?

I divide the code into two parts. The **first part** plots the sum of squared errors versus the μ Poisson parameter for the given goals. The **second part** uses a `BFGS` local optimizer. I preferred not to enter the limits (`bounds`) because the minimum and maximum values vary continuously and are therefore always unknown (goals = [1, 2, 2, 2, 1] is only a example). I would have liked to use an optimizer/solver like Newton-Gauss, but I was advised to use any solver because I am solving a problem with only one dimension and not hundreds.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.stats import poisson
from scipy.optimize import minimize

goals = [1, 2, 2, 2, 1]

# 1 PART
# Plots the sum of squared errors versus the μ Poisson parameter for the given goals
def f(k):
    """Observed data."""
    observed_data = len(list(filter(lambda j: j <= k, goals)))/len(goals)
    return observed_data

def poisson_cdf(mu, k):
    """Poisson CDF."""
    return sum(mu**j/math.factorial(j) for j in range(0, k+1))*math.exp(-mu)

def lsq_error(mu, k_vals):
    """Sum of squares of errors."""
    return sum((poisson_cdf(mu, k)-f(k))**2 for k in k_vals)

# Find the error for values of k in k_vals.
max_value = max(goals)
k_vals= list(range(max_value + 1))
print("Number of Functions: ", k_vals)

###############################################################
# 2 PART
# optimize with `BFGS` local optimizer
result = minimize(lambda x: lsq_error(x[0], k_vals), x0=[0])
print("Final parameter: ", result.x[0]) #1.6931671442067795
```

Thank you all!